# How to Stop A Timer in a LWC Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC component that starts a timer (see timer code below).

This works just fine but the LWC is on a record page.  When I navigate to several records sequentially the timers multiply like rabbits.  One per visited record even though the component is visually "gone" between navigations from the list view to the record page.

How can I stop the timer embedded in the LWC when a record page is refreshed or navigated away from?

In other words, what component event hook can I use from within the LWC itself to stop the timer?

Thanks!

Function that starts the timer:

```
@wire(getLoadLock, {loadId: '$recordId'})
wiredLoadLock(result) {

    if(result) {

        this._wiredValue = result;
        let data = result.data;
        let error = result.error;

        if (data) {            
            if(data.IsOK) {
                this._loadLock = data.Results;
                this.setBackground();                
                if(this._timerPointer) {
                    window.clearInterval(this._timerPointer);
                }
                this.startTimer();
            }
            else {
                LightningUtil.logError(this, data.Error);
            }
            LightningUtil.displayMessages(this, data.Messages);
        } 
        else if (error) {
            LightningUtil.logError(this, error);
        }
    }
}
```

The timer function:

```
startTimer() {

    let interval = this._loadLock ? (new Date(this._loadLock.Expiration__c)).getTime() - new Date().getTime() : 60000;
    let elem = this.template.querySelector('span.countdown');
    let refreshMe = this._wiredValue;

    this._timerPointer = window.setInterval(

        function() {

            let minutes = Math.floor((interval % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            let seconds = Math.floor((interval % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            elem.innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "; 
            if(interval <= 0) {
                interval = 60000;
                refreshApex(refreshMe);
            }                
            else if(interval != 60000 && seconds == 0) {
                refreshApex(refreshMe);
            }                
            interval = interval - 1000;
        }, 
        1000);
}
```

Stop the timer -- does not seem to work:

```
disconnectedCallback() {
    window.clearInterval(this._timerPointer);
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disconnectedCallback()` to remove the timer with `window.clearInterval(this.timer)` - this code implies that you store the interval id as a class variable rather than a local variable as in your code.

See also the documentation about [Lifecycle Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_lifecycle_hooks)

Comment: Christian -- Thanks for your help and what you describe makes total sense.  However I am still seeing the issue even adding this method.

Comment: What I see is one timer starts for each visit to the record page.  Here are the three methods for completeness.  The original invocation method, the timer method, and the disconnect method.

Comment: Are you able to edit your original question and post all the code there? Or is this not possible because you don't have this privilege yet?

Comment: Christian -- Original post updated with all three function.