# How to detect Salesforce UI navigation in an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex, lifecycle

I have an LWC that adds a timer (in `connectedCallback`) for periodic polling of an imperative apex API in order to do some processing related to the given context (which might be a given record, when used on a Lightning Record Page). The timer is removed when the component is deleted (in `disconnectedCallback`).

Some discoveries around the usage of this component in various pages (tabs and record pages) were somewhat surprising, given the [lifecycle hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lifecycle-hooks.html) available for LWCs. I assume this behaviour is because the Salesforce UI is an SPA (Single Page Application). My discoveries are:

1. When I open a Salesforce UI tab (rather than browser tab) with the component in the page, a timer starts - the component's `connectedCallback` is invoked.
2. When I navigate to a different Salesforce UI page (via a tab, for example) the timer continues. The component's `disconnectedCallback` (which is used to terminate the timer) is **not** called.
3. Opening another page with the component on it starts a new timer, so now I have two going.
4. If I have the component on a record page, for example, navigating to a new record starts a further timer, one for each record visited. The `disconnectedCallback` (and a new `connectedCallback`) only gets called if I return to a record I already viewed.

We've looked at what events we might be able to use to detect the component being removed from view or returning to view so we can cleanly stop/restart the timer, but haven't found anything.

Do you know a way I could do this (some event or other), or an alternative approach that doesn't use a timer that allows for a real-time delay between calls to the imperative Apex?

(I am aware of [this similar Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302588/how-to-stop-a-timer-in-a-lwc-component) but the answer to it is invalid, as covered in my explanation above.)

Comment: I have encountered the same kind of scenario before. If the posted solution doesn't work for you, I am happy to share a solution.

Comment: We *believe* we have a solution using a combination of things including the `CurrentPageReference`. However, please do feel free to post a further answer @MukulMahawariya. It is always good to get answers from people who have already solved a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I assume this behaviour is because the Salesforce UI is an SPA (Single Page Application).

Not entirely. LWR itself doesn't suffer from this problem. See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-jpcrcb?title=LWC%20playground). What you're experiencing is a side effect of how the One app caches components for performance reasons.

In my experience, the most reliable method for detecting navigation is by using `CurrentPageReference` from [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation). Every time the user navigates between elements, the URL will update, and you'll be notified. The `state` property of `pageReference` should give you the details for the current view.

However, you could also detect the record Id changing:

```
#recordId;
@api set recordId(value) {
  if(this.#recordId !== value) {
    this.doApiCall(value);
  }
  this.#recordId = value;
}
get recordId() {
  return this.#recordId;
}
```

Every time there's a navigation to a new record, you'll get the record Id.

Comment: Oooh. Nice. I'll give it a go (then do the voting stuff).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the connected-disconnected callbacks seems to be related to the node API, specifically to the isConnected attribute.

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected)

> A boolean indicating whether or not the Node is connected (directly or indirectly) to the context object, e.g. the Document object in the case of the normal DOM, or the ShadowRoot in the case of a shadow DOM.

It seems like the aura framework, decides when to connect or disconnect a component to and from the dom or shadow dom, and it's not happening as soon as a navigation happens.

Moreover, if you open a record page and then navigate to some other tab, you may find that record page as a hidden HTML piece in the markup if you inspect the page.

I remember having a similar problem some time ago and we've decided to check if the component is currently visible on the page as an indicator of the refresh call.

Here is a sample code I've pulled together:

```html
<template>
    <h1>Timer</h1>
</template>
```

```js
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class TimerProblem extends LightningElement {

    interval = "";
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connected');
        this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.checkVisible(this.template.querySelector("h1"))) {
                console.log("not visible");
            } else {
                console.log("tick");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    checkVisible(elm) {
        var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (!rect.bottom || !rect.top) {
            return false;
        }
        var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
        return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        console.log('disconnected');
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

}
```

While this is obviously an ugly workaround it does the job.

Comment: We also tested checking visibility, though using other mechanisms (that did not work). The timer would have to be left running (though not calling the server) since there are no events to detect when visibility changes. I wondered about using the rectangle but didn't try it, so thanks for confirming the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar kind of problem where we were polling apex continuously from LWC but were not able to stop it when the user changed the tab or sub-tab.

To control this, we tried a lot of options which let us know if the URL has been changed or not.

The final approach that worked for us was **MutationObserver**.
Using this will get to know if the recordId passed to LWC is different in the URL or not.

I am sharing a small gist of code that you can use in your polling to check if the user is on the same tab or not.

```
let getRecordId = location.href.split('/');
let urlRecordId = getRecordId[getRecordId.length - 1];
//extract the recordId from the URL.
new MutationObserver(() => {
  if (this.recordId !== urlRecordId) {
    urlRecordId = url;
    //you can start or stop the polling here.
  }
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

Feel free to ask for a more elaborate solution.

Comment: We use the `MutationObserver` to detect when a new record overlay is closed. I remember there were differences in behaviour depending on whether Locker Service or LWS was enabled, so I'm a little cautious. However, thanks. We'll look see if this might help us simplify our current approach (based on `window.location` and `CurrentPageReference` with a couple of caveats and gotchas).